# How to get only the most specific objectClass from AD server using openLdap?

Tags: active-directory, openldap

When using `ldap_search` to get users from Ad server, I get for each entry several `objectClass`es.

I'm interested only in the most specific `objectClass` in the classes hierarchy.
How do I get it?

for example: for the entry

```
name: user1
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: user
```

I want to get only the "user" `objectClass`.

I noticed that in the programmatic `ldap_search`, the most specific class is returned in the last cell of the values array, that is returned from `ldap_get_values(ld, entry, "objectClass")` function call. Is that by chance or is that a defined behavior?
(in other words, can I rely on this to always be true?)

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sure you can't count on heritance order. The solution for you is to specify the `objectClass` attribute in your ldap search filter, and to cross with `objectCategory` to eliminate computers for example.

```
(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))
```

you'll receive here all the objects of class `user` and `inetOrgPerson` (they are also `user`).

```
(&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(objectCategory=person))
```

you'll receive here all the objects of class `inetOrgPerson` (but not those which are uniquely `user`).

Comment: Is objectCategory sufficient if all I need is to seperate users, computers and groups?

Comment: Yes, this attribute is a kind of transversal attribute done for that. for user and inetOrgPerson objectCategory is Person, for computer it's computer, for group it's group.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that you can count on any inheritance order coming back from a directory.  As far as I know directory results are never guaranteed to be in a specific order.  Most probably return the values in the order they were specified during the add.  Objectclass could be a special case and it would be specified in an RFC.  Another thing you'll have to watch out for is when an object has an auxillary class that is mixed in with it.  Plus that auxillary class could bring in some other parent classes.  You could query the directory's schema and work out the inheritance structure from that and store that off if you're doing this all from your own program.

Answer (score 0):

For a generic approach you cannot rely on objectClass values order, because it's not guaranteed by standard and because an objectclass may be derived from two or more direct superclasses (multiple inheritance).

To get the instantiated objetcclass one usually need the schema information and some extra code to analyze the object class chain.

Having said that I should also say that I've seen the code which in case of Active Directory simply relies on objectClass values order. Active Directory does not support multiple inheritance and seems always return objectClass in order or inheritance. This approach is much easier to implement, but not 100% reliable.